# Apache not linked correctly to OpenSSL

Tags: apache-2.2, openssl

I have downloaded the `httpd-2.4.20` source files and tried to build it using the OpenSSL already installed on the system, which is Openssl 1.0.1t.
I used these commands in order to achieve the desired result:

```
$ CFLAGS='-DSSL_EXPERIMENTAL_ENGINE' ./configure --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl $ --with-pcre=/usr/local/pcre --enable-ssl --enable-so
$ make
# make install
```

My intention is to make Apache, via mod_ssl, be able to use some OpenSSL engines specified in the `openssl.cnf` file. But if I type `ldd httpd` the results do not list the OpenSSL libraries: `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` and '`libssl.so.1.0.0`, but instead:

```
# ldd httpd 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc86eb7000)
    libpcre.so.1 => /usr/local/pcre/lib/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007f9ff8543000)
    libaprutil-1.so.0 => /usr/local/apache2/lib/libaprutil-1.so.0 (0x00007f9ff830f000)
    libapr-1.so.0 => /usr/local/apache2/lib/libapr-1.so.0 (0x00007f9ff80d3000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f9ff7e99000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9ff7ad3000)
    libexpat.so.0 => /usr/local/apache2/lib/libexpat.so.0 (0x00007f9ff78a0000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f9ff7667000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f9ff7462000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055cbf518d000)
```

Since I have explicitly specified `--with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl`, which is the installation directory of OpenSSL, why I am not able to use its libraries?

Answer (score -1):

Why do you compile apache on your own instead of using the package that is provided by your vendor (distribution)?

If you compile on your own you have issues like this and security updates also requires repeated efforts.

Comment: I need to compile the Apache on my own because it have to use my OpenSSL with the right `openssl.cnf` file configuration. If I just install it from package manager, it won't be able to read the `openssl.cnf` file. This file contains a reference to an OpenSSL ENGINE that I have created, like a shared library.